# Two conditions for one field in MySQL WHERE

Tags: mysql, where-clause

Is there a way for me to have two conditions on one field in MySQL Where?... I have a field called `type` and I want to do this:

```
WHERE `type` != 'name' AND `type` != 'photo'
```

I'm hoping for a better way to do that, so I could compare `type` to two possible options?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't that be an AND instead of an OR?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you mean AND - you probably do, because OR will always match :) -

```
WHERE `type` != 'name' AND `type` != 'photo'
```

then

```
WHERE `type` NOT IN ('name', 'photo')
```

should cut it.

Comment: Please note that this is not always the best option. Using IN could make some queries on large tables very slow.

Comment: @Pekka웃 please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47167512/not-correct-result-two-conditions-for-one-field-in-mysql-where

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
where type not in ('name','photo')
```