# not correct result Two conditions for one field in MySQL WHERE

Tags: mysql

my Query: any result with this query

```
SELECT
  ref,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  transaction
WHERE (`type` = 10
    OR `type` = 11)
  AND player = 1195
GROUP BY transaction.`ref`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

if on WHERE i change on filed type: i have row with type 10 and 11

```
WHERE `type` = 10

WHERE `type` = 11
```

i see result.

```
  player  reference    type  
  1195      10046         9
  1195      10082         9
  1195      18786        11
  1195      18786        11
  1195      18791        10
  1195      18795        10
  1195      18814        11
  1195      18814        11
  1195      18814        11
  1195      18823        10
  1195      18823        10
  1195      18823        10
```

why?

Comment: It would be worth putting your table data in here as well to help. It could be any number of things. Maybe you only have 1 record that matches all those criteria, maybe you don't have any for that player. Providing sample data would help, a lot.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, it's because of the `OR` in your `Where` clause that you are seeing the results. Show your data and expected results please. This will help us understand your query.

Comment: i have row with type 10 and type 11 and all row player is 1195

Comment: filed type is INT

Comment: i add result on first post.

Comment: Unable to replicate. [Your SQL runs fine for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6ec5/1)

Comment: on my vps dont result with this query

Comment: Are you sure you have the parentheses around the `OR` like you show? BTW, it's often better to use `type IN (10, 11)` instead of `OR` -- it's certainly easier to read.

Comment: How can you see 3 columns, when the select clause only has 2 columns? Your question isn't clear. Please add: `1. sample data` and, `2. expected result` (showing us a result you do NOT want does not help us solve the problem).